# Does Satan actually laugh?

Tags: satan

I've watched a lot of horror movies and I can't help noticing Satan or any demons are often portrayed 'diabolically' laughing somewhere in the movie. But then, Satan is supposed to be our prosecutor* at the Last Judgement and a professional prosecutor would NOT laugh for other reasons. So, my question is - are there any facts in the Book or elsewhere confirming that Satan indeed laughs?

* <sub>I got the idea that Satan will be our prosecutor from the Book of Revelation but please also explain that imagery if my interpretation is wrong.</sub>

Comment: Quick! Someone pull out the Screwtape Letters!

Comment: I think the *"Satan = prosecutor"* line should be the subject of a separate question.

Comment: I like this funny question. +1

Comment: In reply to the question [DO DEMONS EXPERIENCE PLEASURE?](http://spiritualdirection.com/blog/2013/02/28/do-demons-experience-pleasure), exorcist Fr. Fortea says at the end of his answer that, *A demon knows but does not love. The pleasure achieved in doing an evil act is the same as that which a human being feels when he gets revenge on an enemy—it is a pleasure filled with hate.*

Comment: @fredsbend Seen the conversion to comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

"Laughter" has two completely different manifestations: it can be joyous or a cynical sneer.

**Joyous laughter:** not possible for Satan since *Joy* is a [fruit of The Holy Spirit](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%205:22-23&version=NIV1984).

**Sneering:** not recorded in the Bible from Satan, but certainly used by his followers, see both in the Old Testament ([Isaiah 57:3-5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2057:3-5&version=NIV1984)) and New when the Pharisees sneered at Jesus, both regarding His [attitude to money](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+16:14&version=NIV1984) and His failure (in their perception) to [save Himself](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+23:35&version=NIV1984).

*Personal note: I'm pretty sure I can hear the sneering when I read Biblical accounts of Satan, e.g. in [his first appearance](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203:1-5&version=NIV1984).*

Comment: right, how can he be HAPPY to cause sin... he must be holding his laughter or internal stimuli... he is his own evil.

Comment: @deleteMe Please see my comments in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the axiom on which this question is presented is also based on the movies. Namely this fellow from Heaven Can Wait.

[image]

God, in His mighty majestic omniscience hardly needs the prince of lies, darkness and evil to cough up a laundry list of sins.   At the end of all things, the final judgement (as opposed to particular judgement) all your works will just be exposed.

> The judgment will embrace all works, good or bad, forgiven as well as unforgiven sins, every idle word (Matthew 12:36), every secret thought (1 Corinthians 4:5). With the exception of Peter Lombard, theologians teach that even the secret sins of the just will be made manifest, in order that judgment may be made complete and that the justice and mercy of God may be glorified. This will not pain or embarrass the saints, but add to their glory, just as the repentance of St. Peter and St. Mary Magdalen is to these saints a source of joy and honour. [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08552a.htm)

---

And this is what Catholic Encylopedia says concerning Satan appearance at the particular judgement.

> the appearance of angels and demons to bear witness before the judgment seat are regarded as allegorical descriptions (St. Augustine, City of God XX.14). The common opinion is that the particular judgment will occur at the place of death [particular judgement](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08550a.htm)

---

However, the question of whether Satan laughs is an alright one.  Chesterton says that God's hidden virtue is His mirth.  I'd imagine that Satan's most egregious vice is his wicked chortle.  But, I hardly suspect, if he's read the Bible, that he's laughing on the inside.

Comment: But dear Sir, Satan is called 'the accuser' in the Book of Revelation (and elsewhere). In the context of the Book of Revelation I think that literally means 'the prosecutor'. This also explains why Satan is a 'deceiver' because no one expects him to be in that role he has deceived you just now (before my comment)

Comment: I'm going to have to -1 this as not useful for not addressing the issue of Satan being known as "the accuser of the saints". It would be fair to say Catholic's don't see him playing a role in the final judgement, but you would need to state what those kind of verses DO mean and in what sense he is allowed to accuse or prosecute whether on the final day or before.

Comment: @alex I think we have more to fear from God's judgement than Satan's lies.  St. Paul says that our own consciences will accuse us - [see Romans 2:15-16](http://bible.cc/romans/2-15.htm)

Comment: @PeterTurner: Amen to that. It's not the lies he could say about me but the manifest truth about me that [I'd worry about](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/9877/30).

Comment: @caleb, oofta, now that's a comment thread that could stand to be burned with the chaff.

Comment: You're right. I fired up the flame thrower and did away with the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, but films and media in general use their own take on how demons or Satan would act. As far as I'm aware in my reading of the Bible, Satan never laughs. If you interpret the serpent in Genesis to be Satan, he doesn't laugh. Even his depiction in Revelation shows no laughter. In Job, the Adversary (ha-satan) doesn't laugh.

Answer (score -1):

Yes he and his angels often laugh at humans because we are gullible and often stupid and naive. Check out www.staciespielman.com and read her free e-book if you like - she was a new age healer with "spirit guides" who later revealed themselves to be demons who had had been laughing at her **for years** because she believed the lies they told her!

Satan laughs but it is not a good kind of laugh. He hates us, he hates all humans because we can have eternal life. He and the demons -- ALL DEMONS, EVEN TOTORO -- hate us and they are always looking for ways to hurt us (steal, kill and destroy).

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for sharing. The community here prefers answers that can be substantiated, as in sourced. The site strives for an academic quality and unfortunately this answer falls short of that. You can click [edit] to make it better, or just don't worry about it. It's not really that important. What I would like to see is your continued participation. Ask questions, if you have them, or answer question if you know the answer. We're glad you're here.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I hope you'll spend some time browsing the questions and answers here. For some tips on writing good answers, please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)